# WPF Frame how to reload for same URI

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have 2 Menu that will lead to the same page , but will have different
Application.Current.Properties. It use to control some label visibility.

The problem I facing is when I click the first menu my frame will redirect to the page, and break point will stop in typepage.XAML, but when I click the second menu , the page never change because it is not loaded, I found out this by putting a break point the typepage.XAML and the break point did not stop after clicked Second Menu function

My Code : -

```
//First Menu Function 
private void Personalize_Type_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Application.Current.Properties["Type"] = 1;
        Frame1.Source = new Uri("typePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);            
}

//Second Menu Function 
private void Personalize_Typetwo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Application.Current.Properties["Type"] = 2;
        Frame1.Source = new Uri("typePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);            
}
```

Is that a way to reload the same page ?

Comment: If you're navigating to the same page, then surely you wouldn't need to load the page again?

Comment: @MikeEason is that anyway to reload the same page ?

Comment: Have you tried `Frame1.Refresh();`?

Comment: yes i tried it , but not working~

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way to refresh. The refresh will work but under 1 condition which is remove `Frame1.Source = new Uri("typePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);`

```
private void Personalize_Typetwo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        Application.Current.Properties["Type"] = 2;
        frame.NavigationService.Refresh();    

}
```